# CSS/ Javascript - replicate the image style with css3 or javascript (stickers style)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

hi is there anyone can give me some advice on how to replicate the image you see into pure css font+style?

[image]

i tryed this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sdk2S/5/)
**css**

```
 *{
        font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
        font-size:130px;
        color:#444;
        font-weight:bold;
        letter-spacing:-3px;
    }
    body{
        background:url('http://img.ly/system/uploads/007/221/887/large_antani.png') no-repeat left 190px ;
    }
    img{
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
    }
    a{

        text-shadow:
           3px 3px 0 #fff,
         -1px -1px 0 #fff,  
          1px -1px 0 #fff,
          -1px 1px 0 #fff,
           1px 1px 0 #fff,
            0px 2px 2px #ccc, 0px 4px 4px #ccc,0px 6px 6px #ccc;
    }
```

**html**

```
<a>asd</a>
```

any suggestion appriciated.

If also you think it's not possible to replicate this please, tell me, cause if not possible i'm wasting time on it, and i will use image instead of pure `css`.
NB: for the text gradient color i know css is not possible, so i'm planning to use somenthing like this : https://github.com/mrnix/pxgradient

but the huge problem to me it's making the text-shadow appearing as in the image 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally i think you should go for an image in this case. Definitely for such a simple png, it is not worth the effort imo, and you will have the best cross browser support. And I also believe that when it comes to logo's, you need full cross browser compatibility. It is what defines your brand, and the way people will recognize you, so no variations should be allowed.

If you insist on 'coding' your logo, I think you should go for an svg for the closest possible match. I would probably replicate the logo in Illustrator (if you do not have it there already) and save it as an svg from there. Integrating it in a webpage should be easy then...

Comment: +1 for svg, sure using image will be ok, but what if my font-size is 300px? :) i'll need a HUGe png :)))

Comment: not really. Have you tried it? Png is a compressed format, and with such a 'simple' image (compared to a photo for example) file size should be acceptable, even with a 300px font.

Comment: nope, need to try so :) thanks for advice, is SVG cross-browser compatible? i don't give a f** on IE8 and less ;)

Answer (score 3):

I changed your text-shadow to:

```
text-shadow: 0 0 0 20px white, 4px 4px 4px 20px #ccc;
```

It will only work on browsers that support text-shadow spread (which to my knowledge is just IE10), but it is a closer match to the effect in the image.

It's not possible to get the gradient from light-blue to slightly-darker-blue in the text colour, unfortunately, so you'll have to pick a solid colour that works best for you.

Of course, for a cross-browser compatible solution, images are your best bet.

Comment: +1 great thanks, i'll wait for some other answer, in the meantime i found some cool js for text gradient, so i think at the end i will use js for gradient, the main problem is the image stroke+shadow, :P

Comment: That seems very dodgy to me. Sure, it works, but at the cost of a large number of extra nodes being added - on any page with a larger amount of content, it could cause problems in the browser. Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the closest replica for that image.](http://jsfiddle.net/fVwmG/)

Duplicate anchor is needed as `-webkit-background-clip: transparent;` clips out the shadow as well while making gradient effect on text. Yes, this isn't cross-borwser compatible.

HTML:

```
<div class="replica">
    <a class="link">asd</a>
    <a class="shadow">asd</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.replica {
    position: relative;
}
a {
    font-style:italic;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#99FFFF), to(#0DC4F3));
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
a.link {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:-2px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#99FFFF), to(#0DC4F3));
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
a.shadow {
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 0 #fff, -1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #fff, -1px 1px 0 #fff, 1px 1px 0 #fff, 0px 2px 2px #ccc, 0px 4px 4px #ccc, 0px 6px 6px #ccc;
}
```

Comment: this is cool, would like to know if is possible to make it closer, anyway i need to make it cross-browser compatible, so i think i can't use your (awesome) solution :(

Comment: Well, you need cross-browser alternatives/fallbacks for `-webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;` and `-webkit-background-clip:text;`to make it compatible.

Comment: do you know which are these alternatives? :P

Comment: As far as I know there aren't any alternatives yet.

Comment: i found somenthing maybe https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/mask , do you think will this works in your code?

Comment: can't we use a svg for text gradient? do you have any glue?

Comment: Yes, That isn't working. Sorry, I guess there's no alternative for browsers other than webkit.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to get crazy and possibly slow down everything, you can use jquery to make a text shadow for every angle.

follow this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdk2S/91/) to try it

I just did some jquery to make a shadow for every specific angle...  IT IS SLOW, I'm sure even worse with more elements...  but there it is.

```
function stroke(thisEle) {
    var spread = 10; // how far you want the stroke to be
    var shadows = []; //Start an array for every textshadow
    for(var i = 0; i <= 361; i++){ //For every angle
        var angle = i;
        var pointX = spread*(Math.sin(angle)); //find the direction 
        var pointY = spread*(Math.cos(angle)); //of the text shadow
        if(i == 361){ //Give one last text shadow that is black underneath
            var shadow = '20px 20px 20px black'; 
        } else {
            var shadow = pointX + 'px ' + pointY + 'px 0 white';
        }
        shadows.push(shadow); //Add this shadow to the array
    }

    thisEle.css({
        textShadow: shadows //show all shadows (SLOW)
    });
}

$('a').each(function(){ //for each - do everything above
    var thisEle = $(this);
    stroke(thisEle);  
});
```

Then, to do the gradient, just follow this tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/ (NOTE CSS3 AND WEBKIT ONLY)

Otherwise, try something like this: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-gradient-text-effect

Comment: awesome, i edited your shadow, http://jsfiddle.net/sdk2S/96/ now looks more closer :) , thanks!